# Can I use 'being' or should I use 'because'?

Tags: sentence-usage

I saw someone saying this on television actually I really didn't get the meaning. Can I use *being* this way or should I use *because*?

> Your legs are tanned! They were **being** outside.

Comment: I've edited that information into the question. In future, please don't leave out important facts like that.  You now **need** to [edit] to tell us the exact source of the quote, please also provide more context.  Who was saying this? What did the say after and before?  Is it possible that you misheard, or is it possible that the subtitles were wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to make this awkward pair of sentences work:

> Your legs are tanned! They **have been** outside.     (change ***were being*** to ***have been***)
>
> Your legs are tanned **from being** outside.    (change ***were being*** to ***from being***)

There is also your suggestion:

> Your legs are tanned **because** they were outside.    (drop the ***being*** and insert ***because***)

As for what you saw (or think you saw), I have no idea if that was misheard by you, or deliberately made to sound unintelligent by the scriptwriters. There is no way to tell without additional **[details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)**.